# DateDiff Rows Where UserID is a match

Tags: t-sql

On Sql Server 2012 (T-SQL), I would like to analyse the date difference between the end dates and start dates for the same userid, and to see if there is a equal or greater than twelve month gap between times.

So for which ContractID the start date is =>12m than the previous end date.

```
ContractID   UserID    StartDate     EndDate      12m Lapse
     1         779     01/01/2000    01/01/2010     False
     2         779     01/01/2010    01/01/2015     False
     3         779     01/01/2016    NULL           True  
     4        1021     09/03/2008    NULL           False
```

Things perhaps to note are the userID is not in order on the real table, only the contractID is.

Comment: It's not very clear from your question, but if You want the difference between the end date of the previous row and the start date of the current row, you can use the `LAG` window function to do it.

Comment: First, the Microsoft instructions are pretty good on this and you can find them [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx). Use `DATEDIFF(month,StartDate,EndDate)>=12` to determine if 12+ months difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and the [`LAG()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) window function it's quite easy:

Create sample data:

```
DECLARE @T as table
(
    ContractID int,
    UserID int,
    StartDate date,
    EndDate date
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1, 779, '01/01/2000', '01/01/2010'),
(2, 779, '01/01/2010', '01/01/2015'),
(3, 779, '01/01/2016', NULL),  
(4, 1021, '09/03/2008', NULL)
```

The query:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT  ContractID,
            UserID,
            StartDate,
            EndDate,
            LAG(EndDate) OVER(PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY StartDate) As PreviousEndDate
    FROM @T
)

SELECT  ContractID,
        UserID,
        StartDate,
        EndDate,
        CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, ISNULL(PreviousEndDate, StartDate), StartDate) >= 12 THEN
            'True'
        ELSE
            'False'
        END As '12m Lapse'
FROM CTE
```

Results:

```
ContractID  UserID      StartDate  EndDate    12m Lapse
----------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------
1           779         2000-01-01 2010-01-01 False
2           779         2010-01-01 2015-01-01 False
3           779         2016-01-01 NULL       True
4           1021        2008-09-03 NULL       False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE DATEDIFF(M,StartDate,EndDate) >=12
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with SQL Server 2012, there is a function called [Lag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) that will help you get what you need.

The `partition by` of the window function will make sure that its separated by `userID`, and the `order by` will make sure its in `ContractID` order.

```
with prevEndDate as
    (
        select t.contractID
        , t.userID
        , t.startDate
        , t.endDate
        , lag(t.endDate,1,NULL) over (partition by t.userID order by t.contractID asc) as prevEndDate
        from db_name.dbo.myTable as t   
    )
select p.contractID
, p.userID
, p.startDate
, p.endDate
, case when datediff(m,p.prevEndDate, p.startDate) >= 12 then 'True' else 'False' end as [12m Lapse]
from prevEndDate as p
```